# java threads and callbacks

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I just came to a scenario where this question popped on my head and I cannot find an answer, please suggest

We call the callback methods in a thread by any approach, my approach would be:

```
interface Callback {
    void callback(); 
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

    Callback cb; 

    public MyThread(Callback cb) {
        this.bc = cb;
    }

    public void run() {
        // my task to do
        this.cb.callback(); 
    }
}
```

Example of a request made to a servlet on asynchronous mode,

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets012.htm

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/asyncservlet"}, asyncSupported=true)
public class AsyncServlet extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                     HttpServletResponse response) {
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      final AsyncContext acontext = request.startAsync();
      acontext.start(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            String param = acontext.getRequest().getParameter("param");
            String result = resource.process(param);
            HttpServletResponse response = acontext.getResponse();
            acontext.complete();
   }
}
```

> AsyncServlet adds asyncSupported=true to the @WebServlet annotation.
>   The rest of the differences are inside the service method.
>
> request.startAsync() causes the request to be processed
>   asynchronously; the response is not sent to the client at the end of
>   the service method.
>
> acontext.start(new Runnable() {...}) gets a new thread from the
>   container.

**Question** - Is it necessary that all callbacks will be made in multiple threads, when requests are made on  asynchronous mode?

My answer is like .. It need not be, it basically depends on where the callback methods are defined, in one thread or multiple threads.

Please suggest

Comment: Have you simply tried and looked what happens?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: me neither. Anyway, it's hard to tell without specifics of your scenario, ie: Why would the request processing block?